# Obtaining the IP address of a local machine based on computer name using Win32 Network API

Tags: c++, winapi, networking, ip-address

I was looking up http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/network.aspx (How to get the IP address of a machine) and it mentions that *"In the Win32 API this could be accomplished using the NetWork API."*

I wish to use this API using C++ in order to find the IP address of a machine. I have the local computer's name on the network. I've tried looking it up on MSDN but only found the "Network Management" API and it doesn't appear to have the functions I need. I'm assuming I could use Win Socks to figure this out but it seems like a large amount of work for something which should be simple.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Should mention that I am talking about the local IP address, not external.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [`gethostbyname`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function

check this sample

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const char* const host = "thecomputername" ;
  const hostent* host_info = 0 ;
  host_info = gethostbyname(host) ;

  if(host_info)
  {
    std::cout << "host: " << host_info->h_name << '\n' ;

    for( int i=0 ; host_info->h_addr_list[i] ; ++i )
    {
      const in_addr* address = (in_addr*)host_info->h_addr_list[i] ;
      std::cout << " address: " << inet_ntoa( *address ) << '\n' ;
    }
  }
  else herror( "error" ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this locally using [GetAdapterAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in the [IP Helper API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366073%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

> The GetAdaptersAddresses function
>   retrieves the addresses associated
>   with the adapters on the local
>   computer.